# Form that selects files and runs VBA code

Tags: vb.net, vba, excel

Say I have two Excel files and a VBA code file:

File1.xlsx
File2.xlsx
Macro.vb

Using Visual Basic I am attempting to create a Windows form program that will allow me to Browse for File1, File2 and the Macro file.

Once the files are selected, the macro needs to use data from both File1 and File2 and update File1.

Here is a pic of the form, and the lines of code for it.

[image: form pic]

```
Public Class frmStuff

Private Sub btnBrowse1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnBrowse1.Click

End Sub    

Private Sub btnBrowse2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnBrowse2.Click

End Sub

Private Sub btnBrowse3_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnBrowse3.Click

End Sub

Private Sub txtFile1_Text(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtFile1.Text

End Sub

Private Sub txtFile2_Text(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtFile2.Text

End Sub

Private Sub txtMacro_Text(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtMacro.Text

End Sub

Private Sub btnRun_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnRun.Click

End Sub

Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click

End Sub
End Class
```

Do the Excel files need to be open for the macro to run?

If they do could I also please have help on opening the Excel files.

Comment: Clearly the files have to be open in order to use data from them and to run macros. As far as how to open the Excel files, some basic searches here should provide that information. Once you've done that research and made an effort to do the work and you run into difficulties, you can post a question here and ask a **specific** question about the code with which you're having trouble. *I could also please have help on doing somthing basic* is not a specific question. Good luck.

Comment: How are you intending to run a VBA macro which is just in a .vb file?  You would need to somehow get that into a workbook in order to be able to run it. *Why* is it a standalone .vb file and not already contained in a workbook?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, was being a little impulsive. I have since worked on this and have got it working to a certain point.

The issues that I am now having and will post if I can not resolve myself.
Cheers anyway